# What do Cyan/Black Edges mean?

Tags: 3d-view

These Edges from Edit Mode are screwing up my Subdivide. What are they and how do I get rid of them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines appear when you select "Sharp Edges/Vertices" from the "Shading/UVs" menu in edit mode. You can eliminate them by selecting "Smooth Vertices" from the same menu here:[image]

I hope this helped. Happy Blendering! Cheers,
Graves Broderick